# Овочі на парі чи на пару?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, терміни

Завжди за звичкою використовують словосполучення ***“овочі на пару”***. Як підтвердження, стаття [“Овочі на пару в мультиварці”](http://cookery.com.ua/garniri/garniri-z-kapusti/2156-ovochi-na-paru-v-multivarci.html).

Однак сьогодні натрапила ще й на таке ["Готувати у воді чи на парі. Як приготувати овочі?"](http://bonduelle.ua/harchuvannja/infografika/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0/), де є така конструкція "приготування ***їжі на парі***."

Цікавить, як все-таки правильно називати цей вид приготування їжі?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вживання на пару/парі залежить від початкової форми іменника пар/пара.

У [Академічному словнику](http://sum.in.ua/s/par) **пар = пара** (у значенні «газ, у який перетворюється вода при випаровуванні; газоподібний стан води»):

> **ПАР 2**, у, чол.
>
> 1. Те саме, що **пара 2**. *Стовп гарячого пару виривався з-під покришки самовара* (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 64).

Однак, у  [Онлайн коректорі](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0/) знаходимо інформацію:

> Замініть іменник **пар**, якщо мовиться про газ, у який перетворюється вода при випаровуванні, на правильний варіант: **пара**.

У [Літературному слововживанні](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53407/31741.html) знаходимо інформацію, що **пар** (у значенні «газоподібний стан води») не вживається:

> **ПАР** -у. Рілля, залишена на одне літо без посіву: орати під пар, чорний пар.

Отже, правильно вживати **овочі на парі** як похідне від **пара**.